# mobx-react-lite: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I have a simple component that just adds value in screen, but I'm receiving an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') at increment (initialState.js:11:7)`.

App.js:

```
return (
    <IncrementButton store={Store} />
);
```

IncrementButton.js:

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react-lite';
import React from 'react';

export const IncrementButton = observer(({store}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={store.rebate.increment}>Increase</button>
      <h1>{store.rebate.value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
});
```

rootStore.js:

```
import {makeAutoObservable} from 'mobx';
import {initialState} from './initialState';

class RootStore {
  states = initialState;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }
  increaseNumber = () => {
    this.states.rebate.increment();
  };
}

const Store = new RootStore();
export default Store.states;
```

initialState.js:

```
export const initialState = {
  rebate: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Example',
    value: 3000,
    increment() {
      this.value = this.value++;
    },
  },
};
```

I'm also up to new tips since I'm starting with `mobx-react-lite` and only `mobx-react-lite`. It seems really difficult to find documentation about only `mobx-react-lite`. Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is `undefined` inside your `initialState`'s "method".

Remove `increment` from `initialState` and write `increaseNumber` as

```js
increaseNumber = () => {
  this.states.rebate.value += 1;
}
```